# JS str replace Unicode aware

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am sure there is probably a dupe of this here somewhere, but if so I cannot seem to find it, nor can I glue the pieces together correctly from what I could find to get what I need. I am using JavaScript and need the following:

1) Replace the first character of a string with it's Unicode aware capitalization UNLESS the next (second) character is a - OR ` or ' (minus/dash, caret, or single-quote).

I have come close with what I could find except for getting the caret and single quote included (assuming they need to be escaped somehow) and what I believe to be a scope issue with the following because `first` returns `undefined`. I am also not positive which JS/String functions are Unicode aware:

```
autoCorrect = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/^./, function(first) {
    // if next char is not - OR ` OR ' <- not sure how to handle caret and quote
    if(str.charAt(1) != '-' ) {
      return first.toUpperCase(); // first is undefined here - scope??
    }
  });
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you have to use regex?

Comment: ` is not a caret. It's called a grave accent. A caret would be ^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, JavaScript uses UCS-2, not UTF-8.

Handling Unicode in JavaScript isn't particularly beautiful, but possible. It becomes particularly ugly with surrogate pairs such as "", but the [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop can handle that. Do **never** try to use indices on Unicode strings, as you might get only one half of a surrogate pair (which breaks Unicode).

This should handle Unicode well and do what you want:

```
function autoCorrect(string) {
    let i = 0, firstSymbol;
    const blacklist = ["-", "`", "'"];
    for (const symbol of string) {
        if (i === 0) {
             firstSymbol = symbol;
        }
        else if (i === 1 && blacklist.some(char => char === symbol)) {
            return string;
        }
        else {
            const rest = string.substring(firstSymbol.length);
            return firstSymbol.toUpperCase() + rest;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return string.toUpperCase();
}
```

#### Tests

```
console.assert(autoCorrect("δα") === "Δα");
console.assert(autoCorrect("") === "");
console.assert(autoCorrect("d") === "D");
console.assert(autoCorrect("t-minus-one") === "t-minus-one");
console.assert(autoCorrect("t`minus`one") === "t`minus`one");
console.assert(autoCorrect("t'minus'one") === "t'minus'one");
console.assert(autoCorrect("t^minus^one") === "T^minus^one");
console.assert(autoCorrect("t_minus_one") === "T_minus_one");
```